# I faced an issue while opening Jmeter 5.1v log

Tags: jmeter

[image: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError]

While opening JMeter 5.1v in log I came across an issue

> i.e WARN o.j.r.Plugin: Unable to load class:
>   com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.oauth.OAuthSampler
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampler2 I had added oAuth
>   sampler plugins in lib/ext also

please suggest me to overcome this issue

Comment: How did you add the plugin(s)? I wouldn't expect these types of issues when you use the [pluginmanager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Answer (score 0):

The required class - `HTTPSampler2` has been removed as a part of [Bug 60727 - Drop commons-httpclient-3.1 and related elements](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60727) hence the latest version you can use with this `OAuthSample` plugin seems to be [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31)

You can download JMeter 3.1 from [JMeter Archives page](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/)

Comment: tq for ur guidence @Dmitri T

Answer (score 0):

The class `org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler2` has been removed in JMeter v3.2. The corresponding bugzilla entry is [60727](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60727).

The [documentation for the plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/OAuthSampler/) states that the plugin is deprecated. You would probably have to change the [base class in the sources](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/dccdf30102f5ebecfa6f347bdfcfba65a476a4e7/plugins/oauth/src/main/java/com/atlantbh/jmeter/plugins/oauth/OAuthSampler.java#L29).

That seems not to be an easy task.

Comment: Thanks for ur guidance @ Felix Schumacher